# Spring Boot (Gradle & Kotlin) custom library not reading application.yml properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to make an SDK (a custom library) for my Spring Boot microservices using Gradle (with Kotlin DSL) and Kotlin to send emails, reusing most of the stuff and libraries, using AWS SES.

First of all, I don't have a lot of experience on building java libraries, so there could be a lot of stuff that I am not doing correctly. Any feedback is welcome.

Anyways, I want this library to take some properties from the `application.yml` file on the end application (the microservice app itself) to instantiate some of the Beans of the library.

This library uses `JavaEmailService`, and has some parameters to use the local email server when developing in local, or the AWS SES implementation for the deployed versions.

For example, in the Bean configuration of the library I have the following code:

```kotlin
@Configuration
internal class BeanConfig {
  // ... other properties

  @Value("\${sdk.mail.aws.access_key:}")
  private lateinit var awsMailAccessKey: String

  @Value("\${sdk.mail.aws.secret_key:}")
  private lateinit var awsMailSecretKey: String

  @Value("\${sdk.mail.aws.region:}")
  private lateinit var awsMailRegion: String

  @Value("\${sdk.mail.is_local:}")
  private var isLocal: Boolean? = null

  // ... other bean resolves

  @Bean
  fun amazonSimpleEmailService(): AmazonSimpleEmailService {
    if (isLocal == true) {
      return DummyAmazonSimpleEmailServiceImpl()
    }

    if (awsMailAccessKey.isEmpty() || awsMailSecretKey.isEmpty() || awsMailRegion.isEmpty()) {
      throw Exception("Missing AWS parameters (access_key, secret_key, region)")
    }

    return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder
      .standard()
      .withCredentials(
        AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
          BasicAWSCredentials(
            awsMailAccessKey,
            awsMailSecretKey
          )
        )
      )
      .withRegion(Regions.fromName(awsMailRegion))
      .build()
    }
}
```

I want it to take the values from the `application.yml` file on the end application like so:

```yaml
sdk:
  mail:
    is_local: false
    aws:
      access_key: ${AWS_MAIL_ACCESS_KEY:}
      secret_key: ${AWS_MAIL_SECRET_KEY:}
      region: ${${AWS_MAIL_REGION:}
```

I did a custom selection of the dependencies that should be included in the final `jar` file, as I was getting a lot of `ClassNotFoundException` (any recommendations on this part are also welcome, in the Java library `jar` generation). It includes in the final `jar` all the needed dependencies for it to work.

Here the relevant parts of the `build.gradle.kts` file for generation of the `jar` file when I run `./gradlew build`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.10"
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
}

// ... library version, name and trivial info

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.5.0")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.3.7")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:1.5.10")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.5.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.6.RELEASE")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:1.12.131")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2")
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2"))
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.10.3-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

val exportPackages: List<String> = listOf(
    "spring-boot-starter-mail",
    "jakarta.mail",
    "jakarta.activation",
    "spring-context-support",
    "spring-boot-starter/",

    "spring-cloud-starter-aws",
    "spring-cloud-aws-context",
    "spring-cloud-aws-core",
    "javax.mail-api",
    "javax.activation",

    "aws-java-sdk-ses",
    "aws-java-sdk-core",
    "httpclient",
    "httpcore",
    "joda-time"
)

// Here the custom part
tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = true
    from (
        configurations.compileClasspath.get().mapNotNull {
            if (exportPackages.any { exportPackage -> it.path.contains(exportPackage) }) {
                if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it)
            } else null
        }
    )
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}
```

When running `./gradlew build` I get a "sdk-mail-0.0.1-plain.jar" file. This part works pretty well if I included in the final application with that file in the same repo, like so:

```kotlin
implementation(files("lib/sdk-mail-0.0.1-plain.jar"))
```

**THE PROBLEM**

When I publish it in our package repository and I import it in the final application like you would do with any other library:

```kotlin
implementation("com.organization:sdk-mail:0.0.1")
```

It gets imported correctly, and I can use all the classes during development, but when I run the application I found two problems:

- It does not find the `application.yml` properties defined in the final application (it does find them when running the jar built locally)
- It tries to reach EC2 to find AWS credentials (like a default region) but obviously it fails to do so. I guess it would not happen if the properties were found in the first place, so probably this will be fixed when the properties problem is fixed.

Here the publish configuration section in the library's `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
publishing {
    repositories {
        // ... private repository settings
    }
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("default") {
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
}
```

What I really don't understand is that, if I download the published jar in the package repository, and add it like if I generated it building the project locally, it works corretly. What I am gessing is that the published version that gradle downloads has some spring boot dependencies or something like that, but I really don't have any clue.

Could someone please help me with that?